# Adding custom font via CSS class to a bootstrap class line?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I know how to add a custom font to a bootstrap driven page, but I'm not sure if it is possible to add a CSS class to a pre-existing `class` line of bootstrap? Example below, I don't want all 's to have a specific font, except one line.

```
<h1 class="text-center"> Hello World</h1>
```

I want the bootstrap `text-center` but I want to change the font on a CSS file to specify this line only.

Would it be possible to apply something like:

```
.Hello{
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

for that specific line?

Comment: you can try `<h1 class="text-center Hello"> Hello World</h1>`, if it doesn't work add `!important`on your css .Hello class `.Hello{  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

**instead of**
`<h1 class="text-center"> Hello World</h1>`

**use**
`<h1 class="text-center hello-text"> Hello World</h1>`
add `.hello-text{ font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; }` to CSS file

**or else try using**
`<h1 class="hello-text"> Hello World</h1>`
add `.hello-text{ font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; text-align: center; }` to CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have more than one option here
First: Override the original class
Hack into bootstrap main code and apply your font, in bootstrap.css search for text-center, you will see this :

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can change it to this :

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-family : 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

By doing this, any element that has text-center class will have Indie Flower Font.
Option Two: Create your own class name (recommended)

```
.indie-flower-font{
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive !important;
  //we use !important in such utilites classes to avoid any conflicts
 }
```

and for Html

```
<h1 class="indie-flower-font">I AM INDIE FLOWER!</h1>
```

Option Three: Create a Global Rule For all centered text

```
h1.text-center{
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

So basically any h1 with text-center class will have that font.

I would recommend Option 2 However since it's the safest and scalable one.

Comment: Thanks so much for the options, the 2nd one is the best!